# Legend and title to line charts using matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting the below data frame using google charts.

```
 Group  G1  G2
 Hour
  6     19  1
  8     1   2
```

I have plotted the above dataframe in line chart. But i am not able to add legend and title to the line chart. And also, I am trying to increase the size of the line charts as it appears to be very small. Not sure whether do we have these options in matplotlib. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(dft2)
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfg2.plot(legend=True, figsize=(8,8))
plt.legend(ncol=3,  bbox_to_anchor=[1.35, 1], handlelength=2, handletextpad=1, columnspacing=1, title='Legend')

plt.title('Title here!', color='black', fontsize=17)              
plt.xlabel('Hour', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry i screwed up with my dataframe format. I have changed the format of the dataframe now. With this legend does not work.

Comment: What if you change plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5)) to this line:  df.plot(legend=True)

Comment: I have added the changes in the Edit part. Everything works other than resizing the figure.

Comment: You can adjust the size by changing numbers in figsize=(8,8). But if you resize the figure you probably should adjust the legend location also by changing values in this line bbox_to_anchor=[1.35, 1]